# Azure Scale Out WebApp Connection Constantly Switches Between Servers

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling

We have an ASP.NET WebForms website running in an Azure WebApp with automatic "Scale Out" enabled. I can see there are currently two instances running. We have a test page with the following code:

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]
```

If we constantly refresh this page, the IP randomly switches between two different values (presumably for the two different website instances that are running). This is breaking functionality that relies on Sessions, as the Sessions are server-specific.

1. Is there a way to keep users on the same server instead of connecting them to a random server for each request? (I understand this wouldn't fully solve the problem, so my next question is...)
2. Is it not viable to use Session objects with the "Scale Out" feature enabled? If not, what are some other options? If we use cookies, I'm concerned about reaching data limits since we occasionally use Sessions to preserve large data sets for short periods. If we use something like a Redis cache, it adds to our operating costs. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In `Azure App Service` we need to enable `ARR Affinity` to keep the session active in one Server.

The Application requesting routing identifies the user and assigns a **Affinity cookie**. Client establishes the session with the current instance and keeps the instance active until the session expires.

[image]

- `ARR affinity`will not work when we `scale out`  the app service instances, when we scale out, new instances of our app services server will be created and the `ARR Affinity` will fail if the request goes to new server.

Thanks @[ajkuma-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/39015/azure-app-service-arr-affinity-auto-scaling-statef.html)

> If our application is stateful, scaling up would be the best option, If our application is stateless, scaling out gives the greater flexibility and a better scalability potential.

Instead of `Scaling out` we can `Scale up` `App Services plan` by increasing the `size` and `SKU` of our existing `App Service plan` to higher tier with more compute, features and then enable the `ARR affinity`, which helps the sessions remain active and persistent in one Server.

> If we use something like a Redis cache, it adds to our operating costs.

Thanks @[Praveen Kumar Sreeram](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-app-service-sessions-management-in-load-balancing-environment-using-redis/#:%7E:text=So%2C%20the%20conclusion%20here%20is%20%E2%80%9CSessions%E2%80%9D%20wouldn%E2%80%99t%20work,is%20based%20on%20the%20popular%20open-source%20Redis%20cache.)

> when you configure Load Balancer utilizing the auto-scaling capability, "Sessions" wouldn't work as planned in the Azure App Service.
> Another option is to use Redis Cache.

Currently I am using the Standard Tier S1.

[image]

- With auto Scaling Rule, we can scale up and down when it is not required.
- Scale up to `Standard S3`.

One `affinity cookie` will be associated to the app server for each request, even if the app receives repeated requests; this will maintain the session's persistence and activity.
And as new instance of app server won’t be created, the application session will remain active due to `ARR affinity`.

Reference taken from [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/39015/azure-app-service-arr-affinity-auto-scaling-statef.html)